# OpenVPN server in VirtualBox Linux guest with host only adapter

Tags: openvpn, virtualbox

I need to setup a VirtualBox virtual machine that will act as a VPN.
I'm using Vagrant to create the VM on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS client.
I'm using OpenVPN as the VPN server on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server.

OpenVPN is configured to work on the 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0 network. The VPN server itself is 10.8.0.1. Starting OpenVPN and connecting to it shows no error in any log file.

If I configure Vagrant to use a "public network", then I can connect to the VPN and I can ping the VPN server:

```
ping 10.8.0.1 # ok
```

If I configure Vagrant to use a "private network" (with a statically defined 192.168.50.42 IP), then **I can still connect to the VPN but I cannot ping the VPN server anymore**. Anything (SSH, HTTP...) that tries to use the VPN address (10.8.0.1) fails.

```
ping 10.8.0.1 # ko
```

ifconfig on the VPN client:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:10278 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:10278 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:920543 (920.5 KB)  TX bytes:920543 (920.5 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:140 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
      RX bytes:7192 (7.1 KB)  TX bytes:87424 (87.4 KB)

vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
      inet addr:192.168.50.1  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:63895 (63.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:68:95:ee:01:75  
      inet addr:192.168.40.45  Bcast:192.168.40.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3668:95ff:feee:175/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2a01:e35:8af4:2240:ad1b:a074:194:ce3f/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a01:e35:8af4:2240:3668:95ff:feee:175/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:38051 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:26967
      TX packets:26737 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:43426256 (43.4 MB)  TX bytes:3423106 (3.4 MB)
      Interrupt:19
```

route on the VPN client:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.40.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.40.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.50.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
192.168.50.42   192.168.40.254  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
```

Here comes the interesting part: deleting the last route makes the ping work:

```
route del -net 192.168.50.42 gw 192.168.40.254 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev wlan0
```

The problems are:

- this route is back everytime I reset the VM (everytime I do a vagrant up I think)
- I don't know how that would behave on a Windows client
- I need this to be as automated as possible

**Questions:**

- Why do I need to delete what looks like a completely unrelated route on another network for my VPN server to be reachable ? (I'm guessing this has something to do with the IP I use to connect to the VPN server...)
- How can I fix this?

Thank you,